# Добавление элемента в массив (array_push)

Tags: php, массивы

```
function getData($data=''){
    $link = file_get_contents('file.txt'); //открываю файл
    $exploded = explode("\n", $link); //преобразую в массив
    if(!empty($data)){ //если указана $data
        $array = array_push($exploded, $data); //то пытаюсь добавить элемент в массив
        return $array;//отдаю новый массив
    }else{
        return $exploded; //если $data не указана, отдаю старый
    }
}
var_dump(getData('test1')); //результат "int(5)" вместо ожидаемого массива...
```

что я делаю не так, почему не возвращается массив?

Comment: `$link = file_get_contents('file.txt');  $exploded = explode("\n", $link);` => `$exploded = file('file.txt');`

Comment: Оффтопик: Читать весь файл в память не очень хорошай идея. Особенно если потом вы его просто запишете обратно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращайте в обоих случаях переменную `$exploded`, так как функция `array_push` изменяет массив указанный в своих параметрах и возвращает количество элементов после добавление нового.

Подробно описано тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 1):

array_push работает не так.

[Ссылка на документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)

Первым параметром вы указываете массив, **В КОТОРЫЙ** будут вставлены элементы, переданные вторым и далее аргументами.

В вашем случае нужно делать так:

```
if(!empty($data)){
    array_push($exploded, $data); 
    return $exploded;
}else ....
```